# How is Markdown licensed?

Tags: file-formats, specifications

This question probably has a simple answer, but I haven't found it anywhere. I know various Markdown implementations are licensed, but is the Markdown language itself licensed?

The reason I'm asking is to figure out whether the Markdown syntax (``` `` ``` for code, `* *` or `_ _` for italics, etc.) is itself subject to a license.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The syntax of a language is not usually licensed, just the specific implementation of the interpreters and compilers. Programming languages are used to build software like natural languages are used to (let's say) write poems. Specific software implementations could be licensed, like specific poems could be, but the language itself couldn't be.

The particular case of Markdown the language is not licensed. And its reference implementation, [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), a Perl script that implements the parser and HTML generator, is licensed with a 3-Clause BSD [license](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/license).

There was a related question on Software Engineering if you want to read more details:
[What constitutes a programming language and how does one copyright a programming language?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/178776/what-constitutes-a-programming-language-and-how-does-one-copyright-a-programming)

Comment: So you would say that using an existing Markdown compiler would be subject to that compiler's license, whereas writing your *own* Markdown compiler -- using the same syntax that Markdown uses -- would not, correct?

Comment: Exactly, I know there could be more complex cases, but for the case of Markdown, you can write your own interpreter/compiler (or whatever tool that process and do something with Markdown files) and give it the license you want

Comment: NB: You might want to update your answer as  Markdown code does not use a "custom license" but a plain BSD-3-Clause

Answer (score 5):

The [Original Specification](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) by John Gruber has a [licence statement](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/license) plus [RFC 7764](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7764)  and [RFC 7763](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7763) may help to clarify this.

To me it reads very similar to BSD.

Comment: The two RFCs are good reads but they don't address license issues regarding the syntax itself.

Comment: This is exactly a BSD-3-Clause actually, with the common injection of the name that shall not be used eg "Markdown"